# cherrypy password form

Tags: python, html, forms, passwords, cherrypy

I am trying to make a user registration and login for an application I'm working on using the form below.

```
<html><form method="get"  action="login">
Email Address: <input name="email" type="text"><br/>
Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

However the user name and password show up in the url, as does the submit button.

```
http://localhost:8080/login?email=123&password=123&submit=Submit
```

How do I stop this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They show up in the URL because your form is using the GET method, you should be using POST and processing the values on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the POST/GET confusion Shawn points out, you might be interested to look at Cherrypy's built-in [authentication tool](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/BuiltinTools#tools.auth_basic).

Comment: Thanks do you know if it support salted hashes?

Comment: I haven't used it myself; I use CherryPy with Google App Engine, which does its own authentication.

Comment: the tool doesn't even attempt to 'implement' the checking of passwords; you'll have to create a function that deals with validating supplied passwords against whatever stored credentials are apropriate for you.  It's no harder to use salted,hashed passwords than any other option.  You won't use a login-form for this; but to be secure you must use ssl (auth-basic sends passwords unencrypted over the wire)